# how can we use phantom wallet to mint NFT in solana without using minter account

Tags: nft, solana

I have been trying to mint NFT in solana. Have done it in different ways
Mostly every way I tried uses random generated keyPair to first mint tokens and then transfer to our wallet
Is there any way I can mint using my phantom wallet

In the following code minting is performed By minter account that is generated using web3 Keypair.generate  function
Is there any way I can perform this minting directly using phantom wallet

// The code that I tried last is

```
import * as web3 from '@solana/web3.js';
import * as splToken from '@solana/spl-token';
 
 const getProvider = async () => {
    if ("solana" in window) {
      const provider = window.solana;
      if (provider.isPhantom) {
        console.log("Is Phantom installed?  ", provider.isPhantom);
        return provider;
      }
    } else {
      window.open("https://www.phantom.app/", "_blank");
    }
  };

const mintingTest = async () => {
    const phantomProvider = await getProvider();
    const mintRequester = await phantomProvider.publicKey;
    console.log("Public key of the mint Requester: ", mintRequester.toString());

    //To connect to the mainnet, write mainnet-beta instead of devnet
    const connection = new web3.Connection(
      web3.clusterApiUrl('devnet'),
      'confirmed',
    );

    //This fromWallet is your minting wallet, that will actually mint the tokens
    var fromWallet = web3.Keypair.generate();
     
    // Associate the mintRequester with this wallet's publicKey and privateKey
    // This is basically the credentials that the mintRequester (creator) would require whenever they want to mint some more tokens
   // Testing the parameters of the minting wallet
   
    console.log("Creator's Minting wallet public key: ",fromWallet.publicKey.toString());
    console.log(fromWallet.secretKey.toString());
    
    // Airdrop 1 SOL to the minting wallet to handle the minting charges
    var fromAirDropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
      fromWallet.publicKey,
      web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
    );

    await connection.confirmTransaction(fromAirDropSignature);
    console.log("Airdropped (transferred) 1 SOL to the fromWallet to carry out minting operations");

    // This createMint function returns a Promise <Token>
    let mint = await splToken.Token.createMint(
      connection,
      fromWallet,
      fromWallet.publicKey,
      null,
      6, // Number of decimal places in your token
      splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    );

    // getting or creating (if doens't exist) the token address in the fromWallet address
    // fromTokenAccount is essentially the account *inside* the fromWallet that will be able to handle the              new token that we just minted
    let fromTokenAccount = await mint.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(
      fromWallet.publicKey,
    );

    // getting or creating (if doens't exist) the token address in the toWallet address
    // toWallet is the creator: the og mintRequester
    // toTokenAmount is essentially the account *inside* the mintRequester's (creator's) wallet that will be able to handle the new token that we just minted
    let toTokenAccount = await mint.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(
      mintRequester,
    );
    
    // // Minting 1 token
    await mint.mintTo(
      fromTokenAccount.address,
      fromWallet.publicKey,
      [],
      1000000 // 1 followed by decimals number of 0s // You'll ask the creator ki how many decimals he wants in his token. If he says 4, then 1 token will be represented as 10000
    );
    
    console.log("Initial mint successful");

    
    // This transaction is sending of the creator tokens(tokens you just created) from their minting wallet to their Phantom Wallet
    var transaction = new web3.Transaction().add(
      splToken.Token.createTransferInstruction(
        splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        fromTokenAccount.address,
        toTokenAccount.address,
        fromWallet.publicKey,
        [],
        1000000, // This is transferring 1 token, not 1000000 tokens
      ),
    );
        
    var signature = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      connection,
      transaction,
      [fromWallet],
      {commitment: 'confirmed'},
    );

    const creatorTokenAddress = mint.publicKey;
    const creatorTokenAddressString = mint.publicKey.toString();

    console.log("SIGNATURE: ", signature); //Signature is basically like the paying party signs a transaction with their key.
    console.log("Creator Token Address: ", creatorTokenAddressString);
    console.log("Creator Minting Wallet Address: ", mint.payer.publicKey.toString());
    
    let creatorTokenBalance = await toTokenAccount.amount;
    console.log("Creator's Token Balance: ", creatorTokenBalance);
  };
```

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question, but you'll probably have an easier time with the Solana wallet adapter package, which provides easy connections to many different wallet providers, including Phantom: https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this easily using [`@metaplex-foundation/js`](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js)

Here's a snippet

```js
import { Metaplex, token } from "@metaplex-foundation/js";
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"));
const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection)
  // if you have to provide the wallet identity, you can pass it here
  .use(walletAdapterIdentity(wallet))

const task = metaplex.tokens().createTokenWithMint({
  // you can supply additional parameters here
  // by default, any accounts with authority will use the identity given above
  initialSupply: token(100_000_000_000),
})

const tokenInfo = await task.run()
```